# How to Add Left and Right buttons in Swiper from App folder in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**I am Using React Native Swiper now i want to add left and right buttons from app folder, this is my code**

```
<Swiper style={styles.wrapper}
          showsButtons
          >
    <View style={styles.slide1}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Hello Swiper</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.slide2}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Beautiful</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.slide3}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>And simple</Text>
    </View>
  </Swiper>
```

**this is my left and right buttons code but don't know where to use it**

```
const leftArrow = require("./resource/leftIcon.png");
const rightArrow = require("./resource/rightIcon.png");
```

Comment: you can use `Image` to add images in your app [Image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image)

Comment: this code defaultly add left and right arrow buttons but i want to add my own left and right buttons